# cannot run powershell script with pywinrm

Tags: powershell, python-2.x, winrm

Here we can see examples:
https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm
how to control windows through pywinrm and powershell script
it's work.

but in case

```
ps_script = """$strComputer = $Host
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:Path + ";C:\Python27\Scripts", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
Restart-Computer 
"""
```

it add python to the PATH, but don't restart Windows.

in case

```
ps_script = """Write-Host "hello"
    """
```

i see "hello" in terminal of my machine, not remote.

what is wrong?

Comment: Couple of thoughts. What version of Windows are you trying to restart? With what version of PowerShell? If I remember correctly, Restart-Computer wasn't added until PowerShell 3.0. Secondly what happens if you add the `-force` parameter?

Comment: @BenH, "restart-computer -force" give success. But what rights? Windows server 2012, powershell 3.0 My user is already in administrative group.

Comment: Actually, `Retart-Computer -Force` AFAIR is just ignoring the fact that there are sessions active on the remote box. W/o it, if any session is present, PowerShell will return an error. Check `std_err` of your `response` object that you get from (just guessing, as you skipped that part of your code) `run_ps` method.

Answer (score 1):

The way pywinrm works is:

- connect to WinRM in a fashion similar to `winrs` command on Windows
- when you decide to run PowerShell script - it's converted to a format acceptable by `powershell.exe -encodedCommand` (see the line that calls PowerShell in the [pywinrm code](https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm/blob/master/winrm/__init__.py#L49-L50))
- the result is transferred back to python, so that you can `print` it, or do whatever you need

Not sure what is your expectation from `Write-Host` - it's just a cmdlet that writes to the application hosting PowerShell (in case of `pywinrm` - that will be `PowerShell.exe`) and the host is responsible to handle it - in your case, write it to `std_out`. So it's not surprising it arrived to your console I guess.

Regarding Restart-Computer - it tends to error out when there are active users. That message will end up in `std_err` of pywinrm code - you may want to analyse `return_code` and respond depending on the value:

```
session = Session(...)
result =  session.run_ps(command)
print result.std_out
if result.status_code != 0:
    print "Error: %s" % result.std_err
```

I suspect you didn't do anything with `std_err`, so any errors PowerShell was throwing at you remain silent.

Comment: I try this
`r = s.run_ps(ps_script)  print(r.std_err)`
and there is silence in terminal